# What happens when cosmic background microwaves enter a bound system?

Tags: space-expansion, boundary-conditions, cosmic-microwave-background

Gamma radiation after spending eons in expanding space have now “stretched “ into microwaves. What happens when these waves enter a bound system like a galaxy or galaxy cluster. Expanding space stretched them. What happens when they arrive at a place where space has not expanded? Is it likely that they were longer waves but contract to microwaves once they enter our system?

Comment: Space expands everywhere, inside or outside the galaxy. What you are describing is the gravitational blueshift. It exists, but is significant only near black holes or neutron stars.

Comment: @safesphere i thought gravity fields countered the expansion. So all of space expands at the same rate, even the space between the atoms in a person?

Comment: No, not like that. Imagine a river flowing into the sea. At the delta, the narrow stream of the river vastly expands flowing now in all directions in the sea. The stream carries fallen leaves and branches. The separate leaves will be taken apart by the stream expansion and will keep flowing farther apart from each other. However, the leaves bound by branches will stay together despite the fact that the stream is expanding even inside the branches. So yes, space expands even between atoms, but it does not move the atoms apart from each other. Space in your room expands out through the walls.

Comment: Gravity does slow down the expansion, but not the way you implied. Bodies bound by gravity stay together, because they are bound, not because gravity slows or stops the expansion. You can blind two rocks in space with a rope instead of gravity and the rope will indeed keep the rocks bound without gravity. A CMB photon received at such a rock will not be blueshifted despite the fact the rocks are bound. However the same photon will be very slightly blueshifted on the Earth, because of the gravity of the Earth. So you could interprete this as that gravity slightly slows down the space expansion.